# ArcGIS Pro reducing multiple rasters to minimum extent

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I have multiple (approx 20) rasters. They all mostly overlap in extent with each other, but each raster has various pixels missing that others do not. Ultimately, I need all rasters to have the exact same extent (for use in species distribution modeling). Is there function/code to quickly reduce the extent of all rasters such that all extents are exactly the same?